# Что означает команда section loop в Smarty?

Tags: php, html, smarty

Всем привет

В смарти я не в зуб ногой, поэтому прошу помощи

```
            {section loop=$items name=key} 
{foreach from=$output.items item=item key=key name=name}
```

Что это значит?Как я понимаю, есть некий шаблон items.tpl?Мне нужно оттуда удалить кое что

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используется для обхода массивов, на подобее `foreach`

[Оф документация](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/language.function.section.tpl)